# Why does buildah fail running inside a kubernetes container?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, buildah

Hey I'm creating a Gitlab pipeline and I have a runner in Kubernetes.
In my pipeline I am trying to build the application as container.

I'm building the container with `buildah`, which is running inside a Kubernetes pod. While the pipeline is running `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` shows the buildah pod:

```
NAMESPACE        NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
gitlab-runner    runner-wyplq6-h-project-6157-concurrent-0qc9ns   2/2     Running   0          7s
```

The pipeline runs
`buildah login -u gitlab-ci-token -p ${CI_BUILD_TOKEN} ${CI_REGISTRY}` and
`buildah bud -t ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/${CI_COMMIT_BRANCH}:${CI_COMMIT_SHA} .`
with the Dockerfile using `FROM parity/parity:v2.5.13-stable`.
Buldah bud however fails, and prints:

```
Login Succeeded!
STEP 1: FROM parity/parity:v2.5.13-stable
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob sha256:d1983a67e104e801fceb1850a375a71fe6b62636ba7a8403d9644f308a6a43f9
Copying blob sha256:3386e6af03b043219225367632569465e5ecd47391d1f99a6d265e51bd463a83
Copying blob sha256:49ac0bbe6c8eeb959337b336ceaa5c3bbbae81e316025f9b94ede453540f2377
Copying blob sha256:72d77d7d5e84353d77d8a8f97d250120afe3650b85010137961560bce3a327d5
Copying blob sha256:1a0f3a523f04f61db942018321ae122f90d8e3303e243b005e8de9817daf7028
Copying blob sha256:4aae9d2bd9a7a79a688ccf753f0fa9bed5ae66ab16041380e595a077e1772b25
Copying blob sha256:8326361ddc6b9703a60c5675d1e9cc4b05dbe17473f8562c51b78a1f6507d838
Copying blob sha256:92c90097dde63c8b1a68710dc31fb8b9256388ee291d487299221dae16070c4a
Copying config sha256:36be05aeb6426b5615e2d6b71c9590dbc4a4d03ae7bcfa53edefdaeef28d3f41
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
time="2022-02-08T10:40:15Z" level=error msg="Error while applying layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: permission denied" 
error creating build container: The following failures happened while trying to pull image specified by "parity/parity:v2.5.13-stable" based on search registries in /etc/containers/registries.conf:
* "localhost/parity/parity:v2.5.13-stable": Error initializing source docker://localhost/parity/parity:v2.5.13-stable: pinging docker registry returned: Get https://localhost/v2/: dial tcp [::1]:443: connect: connection refused
* "docker.io/parity/parity:v2.5.13-stable": Error committing the finished image: error adding layer with blob "sha256:3386e6af03b043219225367632569465e5ecd47391d1f99a6d265e51bd463a83": ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: permission denied
...
```

I am thinking of 2 possible causes:
First the container is build and then it is stored inside the kubernetes pod before transfering it to the container registry. Since the Pod does not have any persistent storage, it fails writting, hence this error.

The second is that The container is build and pushed to the container registry, for some reasons it has no permissions to it and fails.

Which one is it? And how do I fix it?
If it is the fist reason, do I need to add persistent volume rights to the serviceaccount running the pod?

Answer (score 0):

gitlab runner needs root privileges, add this line into [runner.kuberentes] in gitlab configuration

privileged = true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What if root cannot be used due to security.